# Is it possible to push a ViewController in ViewModel Object or Class

Tags: ios, model-view-controller, mvvm, uiviewcontroller, swift4

Is it possible to push an UIViewController from ViewModel Object. When I'm trying to push, the statements are executing but there is no any change in UI. This is my code,

```
@objc func attemptQuiz(sender: UIButton){
    UserDefaults.standard.setValue(sender.tag, forKey: "Quiz_ID")
    let quizListVC = QuizList_ViewController(nibName: "QuizList_ViewController", bundle: nil)
    let attemptVC = AttemptQuiz_ViewController(nibName: "AttemptQuiz_ViewController", bundle: nil)
    quizListVC.navigationController?.pushViewController(attemptVC, animated: true)
}
```

Here, func attemptQuiz and it's calling is in ViewModel object/class of 
   QuizList_ViewController  not in UIViewController Class

Comment: You are creating a new instance of `QuizList_ViewController` and attempting to push from that rather than the instance that is currently onscreen. You probably want `self`  Also the use of _ is not idiomatic in iOS development;  you should use camelCase

Comment: If I use    'self'    instead of     'quizListVC'     ,then there is no any navigation controller to push the    'attemptVC'  , because self represents viewModel and there is no any navigationController to viewModel

Comment: I was thrown because you have an `@IBAction` method - You should not have `@IBAction` methods in your ViewModel - These should be in the view (Which is actually a `UIViewController` in MVVM on iOS).  Then `self` can be used in the push